# Gerar entidades a partir das tabelas com JBossTools

Tags: eclipse

Criei um projeto JPA e a partir do recurso **JPA Tools > Generate Entities from Tables** quero gerar as entidades referentes a cada tabela de minha base de dados.

Tentei seguir um [tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm) no site do Eclipse, contudo não funcionou. Acredito que o tutorial tenha sido feito numa versão do JBoss Tools diferente da que estou usando, visto que a que estou usando apresenta uma tela de configuração diferente como pode ser visto na imagem. Utilizo a versão do JBoss Tools 4.2.2.Final.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Como preencher de forma adequada esta tela para assim criar minhas entidades?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"No meio do caminho tinha uma pedra
 
tinha uma pedra no meio do caminho
 
tinha uma pedra 
no meio do caminho tinha uma pedra[...]"* Carlos Drummond de Andrade

Brincadeiras, à parte, encontrei o motivo de não ter conseguido fazer a configuração. Fiz um breve passo a passo que vai auxiliar quem estiver com o mesmo problema ou para aqueles que venham se deparar com o mesmo.

**INSTRUÇÕES**

- Crie um projeto JPA em **new > JPA Project**;
- Configure os campos **Projetct name** com o nome do seu projeto; o campo **Target runtime** com a versão de sua runtime; e no campo **Configuration** escolha a opção **Basic JPA Configuration** e clique no botão Next;

[image: Configuração do projeto JPA]

Na tela JPA Facet (duas telas após a tela JPA Project) você deve:

- Clicar em **Add connection** e configurar uma conexão com a sua base de dados; Após isso é só clicar no botão Finish;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pronto agora o seu projeto JPA já está configurado e pronto para a geração de suas entidades. Agora é só acionar o recurso **JPA Tools > Generate Entities from Tables** clicando com botão direito do mouse sobre o projeto. O resultado é figura abaixo. Vocẽ seleciona as tabelas e a ferramenta cria as entidades já mapeadas para você. Recurso incrível!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código abaixo mostra o código da entidade Autor criado a partir da tabela autor e das relações com esta tabela:

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * The persistent class for the autor database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="autor")
@NamedQuery(name="Autor.findAll", query="SELECT a FROM Autor a")
public class Autor implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    private String nome;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to AutorLivro
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="autor")
    private List<AutorLivro> autorLivros;

    public Autor() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public List<AutorLivro> getAutorLivros() {
        return this.autorLivros;
    }

    public void setAutorLivros(List<AutorLivro> autorLivros) {
        this.autorLivros = autorLivros;
    }

    public AutorLivro addAutorLivro(AutorLivro autorLivro) {
        getAutorLivros().add(autorLivro);
        autorLivro.setAutor(this);

        return autorLivro;
    }

    public AutorLivro removeAutorLivro(AutorLivro autorLivro) {
        getAutorLivros().remove(autorLivro);
        autorLivro.setAutor(null);

        return autorLivro;
    }

}
```

**Referências**

- *[Generating entities from tables](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jpt.doc.user%2Ftasks021.htm)*
- *[Creating a Hibernate Console Configuration](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.3.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/plugins.html#creat_console_conf)*